# Laravel Subselect with own table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following query:

```
    $users = User::join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id')->select([
        'users.id',
        'users.promoter_id',
        'users.family_name',
        'users.name',
         ...
```

The users.promoter_id is still an ID from the users table. I want to add the family_name and the name for the promoter in that query too.

How can i make that subquery inside my OWN table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-joining scenario. You can do it by creating an alias of your `Users` table and then joining with `Users`.

```
$users = User::join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id')
                ->leftJoin('users as promoters', 'promoters.id', '=', 'users.promoter_id')->select([
        'users.id',
        'users.promoter_id',
        'users.family_name',
        'users.name',
        'promoters.family_name as promoter_family_name',
        'promoters.name as promoter_name',
        ...
```

Another way, in your `User` model define a relation

```
public function promoter()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'promoter_id', 'id');
}
```

Now Rewrite your query in controller

```
$users = User::with('promoter')->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id')->select([
         ...
```

Now you can access promoter details by `$user->promoter->name, $user->promoter->family_name` and so on.

Also you can do the same for `Country` too, by defining a country relationship instead of join in your `User` model and then `User::with('promoter', 'country')->...`

Comment: Thanks. My Problem is, ill need this for a query for a datatables plugin. So it should be done with a query

Comment: OK. Got it. Can you give a try with this: 

`$users = User::join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id')
    ->leftJoin('users as promoters', 'promoters.id', '=', 'users.promoter_id')->select([
        'users.id',
        'users.promoter_id',
        'users.family_name',
        'users.name',
        'promoters.family_name as promoter_family_name',
  'promoters.name as promoter_name',
        ...`

Check updated answer.